# CGRect, CGContextAddLineToPoint, etc not accurately drawing. iOS xcode objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-graphics, cgcontext

I wish to draw a line with length equal to the width of UIView frame.

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGRect squareFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenWidth);
self.frame = squareFrame;
NSLog(@"Frame height: %f", screenWidth); // since it's square, width = height
```

logs -> **Frame height: 375.000000**

And i draw a line:

```
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.6);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 45, 0);
//use width of the frame as the height for the line
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 45, screenWidth);
//or  
//CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 45, self.frame.size.width);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
NSLog(@"Line height: %f", screenWidth);
NSLog(@"Frame height: %f", self.frame.size.width);
```

logs ->

**Line height: 375.000000**

**Frame height: 375.000000**

---

But the line is being drawn **shorter** than the height of the frame.

Why is this happening? How can i fix this?

[image]

Comment: And you do nothing else in `drawRect:`? This sounds as if you are offsetting the origin of the context somehow, by applying a transform on it. Also, have you tried drawing a dot at 45, 0 to see if you can see it? It could be that the view itself is offset somehow, and lies under the nav bar.

Comment: I'm with HenriN; you've got a vertical offset somewhere… draw a diagonal from 45, 45 to 375,375 and see if it's where you think it should be.